# Как написать urls в django?

Tags: django

Как исправить urls.py чтобы не было ошибки?

> Exception Type:   TypeError
>   Exception Value:
>   index() missing 1 required positional argument: 'quiz_id'

urls.py

```
url(r'^registration/$', views.signup, name='signup'),
url(r'^registration/quizes', views.index),
```

views.py

```
def index(request, quiz_id):
    return render(request, 'quiz.html', context={'quize': quize})

def add_quiz(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        quiz_name = request.POST.get("quiz_name")
        user = request.POST.get("user")
        quiz = Quiz()
        quiz.name = quiz_name
        quiz.user = User.objects.get(pk=user)
        quiz.save()
        return HttpResponse(quiz_id)
```

Comment: Эм, ну так в тексте ошибки написано в чём проблема, что вам непонятно?

Comment: не могу понять, как это исправить, ведь с quiz_id все впорядке

Comment: Окей, что такое по-вашему quiz_id и почему вы думаете что с ним всё в порядке?

Comment: quiz_id - это каждый новый созданный quiz, а впорядке всё, потому что консоль на него не ругается

Comment: Блин, я даже не знаю с чего начать. Давайте что ли так: когда вы открываете страницу `registration/quizes`, у вас запускается функция `index`. Эта функция имеет два аргумента. В аргументе `request` Django передаёт свой объект запроса. А что вы ожидаете увидеть в аргументе `quiz_id` и откуда Django возьмёт значение для этого аргумента?

Comment: Разве django не может взять значение из "        return HttpResponse(quiz_id)
"?

Comment: Эта строчка находится в функции `add_quiz`. Эта строчка сработает, только если функция будет вызвана. Почему вы считаете, что эта функция будет вызвана? Кто по-вашему вызовет эту функцию и почему?

Comment: То есть ее нужно вызвать, а потом использовать quiz_id?

Comment: Эм, нет. Я даже не знаю, как вам всё объяснить, у вас полная каша в голове. Вы совершенно не понимаете, как будет выполняться код и что будет происходить со всеми переменными. Я не могу придумать ничего лучше, кроме как отправить вас изучать основы языка программирования Python, увы.